# Compare Two different formats of the DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have `EndDate` column in my table which accepts records like this

**2014-10-29 00:00:00.000**

Now I want to compare this `DateTime` with **present date** . For that , I did like this :-

```
 var today=DateTime.Now;

 var LstEvents = (from t in _context.Tournaments
                             where t.SiteId == siteId && t.EndDate != null
                             && t.EndDate < today
                             select t).ToList();
```

But `t.EndDate < today` is not returning results as I wanted . I did **Add Watch** for today and checked the value and it's format was like

**today    {11/3/2014 8:12:00 PM}  System.DateTime**

Therefore my dates are unable to be compared . 
Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks !!

Comment: `DateTime` has no format, a string has. What type has the `EndDate` column?

Comment: datetime @TimSchmelter

Comment: `DateTime`s are compared by _value_, not by formatted value.  Something else is throwing off your results.

Comment: 1) DateTime.Now returns current time (including hour and minutes and seconds and ticks)

Comment: I didn't formatted any DateTime values @DStanley

Comment: @TusharRaj: use `DateTime.Today`

Comment: @nsinreal yes and you can see the column `EndDate` is also a `datetime` so it also includes hour and minutes and seconds and tick

Comment: could it be an issue at siteId? if you do var lstDates = _context.Tournaments.Where(c => c.SiteId == siteId).Select(c => c.EndDate).Distinct().ToList(), what does the result look like in the debugger? Are there any items where EndDate < today?

Comment: @TusharRaj Right, so the format should be irrelevant when comparing them. Why then do you think they are "unable to be compared"?

Comment: @TimSchmelter you mean `DateTime.Today` will check this :-  't.EndDate < today` ??

Comment: @DStanley i just thought may be due to formatting issues . I myself wasn;t clear what was the issue behind not being compared .

Comment: downvoter ..care to comment please . And we all here to share knowledge . I don't know in the meantime i am clearing my doubts someone just downvote by himself even without clearing my concepts . Applauds ..Kudos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I have pasted was absolutely correct . I got to know that `DateTime` format is irrelevant . Whether it is coming from database or I have used it in `C#` code . I was bit confused as I thought that if the `DateTime` record in database is set in some format then it cannot be compared with the `DateTime` value in C# . Either we have to change the format or do something . Anyway , Thanks guyzz for your help.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

They *are* comparable. What you see is the *string representation* of your date that takes a *format* and a *culture* into account.

If you're seeing this from the debugger, then it shows  the result of `ToString()` against your instance, i.e. using the general date and time format specifier ('G') and the culture of the current thread.

(edit: believe this is what he is referring to)

[image]

Comment: Can you show me some code . I am unable to get this @ken2k

Comment: I don't believe this is a code item, per se. I think ken2k is talking about looking at the value as it appears inside of the IDE.